# Trying to send records from database table with mail()

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am working with XAMPP and I want to select a random record from my database table and send it in an email. I am using [Test Mail Server Tool](https://toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/) but I am receiving the next error:

> Warning: mail(): Bad Message Return Path in C:\xampp\htdocs\dailyapp\sender2.php on line 24
> Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.

What could be happening here? Any idea?

PHP code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dapp";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$recipient = "mdrr5545@gmail.com";


$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_messages ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    ($row = $result->fetch_assoc());
    $subject = $row["subject"];
    $message = $row["message"];
    
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message)) {
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "All good";
    }
    
    else {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }
}

    else {
    echo 0;
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add and header like this

```
$header = array(
    'From' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    'Reply-To' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
);
```

And enter your own information

And uise it in the mail function

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $message,$header)
```

Comment: I just want to know why this was necessary? I would appreciate it if you explain a little bit...